# How to convert a sequence of space-separated numbers in a string to ints

Tags: c++, string, c++11, type-conversion, integer

I am trying to convert string element to integer using `stoi` function in C++11 and using it as parameter to `pow` function, like this:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s = "1 2 3 4 5";

    //Print the number's square
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i += 2)
    {
        cout << pow(stoi(s[i])) << endl;
    }
}
```

But, i got an error like this:

```
error: no matching function for call to 
'stoi(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char> >::value_type&)'
cout << pow(stoi(s[i])) << endl;
```

Anyone know what is the problem with my code?

Comment: The problem is that `s[i]` is, obviously, a `char`. One character. Now take a look at what the parameter to `stoi`() must be, and you should be able to figure it out by yourself.

Comment: `stoi` works with `std::string` (and `std::wstring`), but `s[i]` is a `char`.

Comment: Does it work if I use `substr` function because from what I read, it returns string type?

Comment: @AkhmadZaki Yes, `substr` will work.

Comment: Are you sure your integers need to be in a string? It'd be better to use array of integers if possible.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `stoi()` will not work with `char`. Alternatively you can use `std::istringstream` to do this. Also `std::pow()` takes two arguments the first being the base and the second being the exponent. Your comment says the number's square so...

```
#include <sstream>

string s = "1 2 3 4 5 9 10 121";

//Print the number's square
istringstream iss(s);
string num;
while (iss >> num) // tokenized by spaces in s
{
    cout << pow(stoi(num), 2) << endl;
}
```

Edited to account for numbers larger than single digit in the original string s, since the for loop approach breaks for numbers larger than 9.

Comment: What if s contains a number > 9 ?

Comment: yes, I forgot to include the exponent. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Is the above code still work for integer with number of digit > 1 ?

Comment: @AkhmadZaki yes it does

Comment: It's better to use `std::istringstream` and not `std::stringstream` so the compiler can detect an accidental `<<`.

Answer (score 1):

`stoi()` works fine if you use `std::string`.
So,

```
string a = "12345";
int b = 1;
cout << stoi(a) + b << "\n";
```

Would output:

```
12346
```

Since, here you are passing a `char` you can use the following line of code in place of the one you are using in the for loop:

```
std::cout << std::pow(s[i]-'0', 2) << "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Comment: This trick is only guaranteed to work as long as every character in the string is in the range `'0'` to `'9'`. A single space in the string and you risk undefined behaviour. It's also harder to read.

Comment: This one should be accepted as the answer in an engineering way

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s = "1 2 3 4 5";
    istringstream iss(s);
    while (iss)
    {
        string t;
        iss >> t;
        if (!t.empty())
        {
            cout << pow(stoi(t), 2) << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.